# In C++, how to express the largest possible value of a type via its variable name?

Tags: c++, numeric-limits

Assuming there is a declaration in a header file you don't control that states something like:

```cpp
static const uint16 MaxValue = 0xffff;  // the type could be anything, static or not
```

Inside a file that includes the above you have code like this:

```cpp
int some_function(uint16 n) {
   if (n > MaxValue) {
     n = MaxValue;
   }
   do_something(n);
   ...
}
```

The compiler will warn that the if statement is always false because `n` cannot be larger than 0xffff.

One way might be to remove the code.  But then if later someone wants to change the value of `MaxValue` to something lower you have just introduced a bug.

Two questions:

- Is there any C++ templates or techniques that can be used to make sure the code is removed when not needed (because `MaxValue` is 0xfff) and included (when `MaxValue` is not 0xffff)?
- Assuming you want to explicitly write an extra check to see if `MaxValue` is equal to the limit the type can hold, is there a portable technique to use to identify the maximum value for the type of `MaxValue` that would work if later the code of `MaxValue` is changed?

  - Meaning: how can I infer the maximum value of type via its **variable** name?

    - I would prefer not using the `limits.h` or `<limit>` constants like `USHRT_MAX`, or event not using `std::numeric_limits<uint16>` explicitly.
    - Can something like `std:numeric_limits<MaxValue>`  be used?

Comment: Turn off stupid warnings.

Comment: `n` can't be greater than `0xffff`, so that check doesn't make sense at all? What are you actually trying to do? Sounds like an xy-problem for me.

Comment: You can use `if constexpr` to eliminate unused code at compile-time. And you can use `decltype` to get the type of a variable for use in templates, eg: `std::numeric_limits<decltype(MaxValue)>::max()`

Comment: I know n can't be larger that the max value of the type but i also know for the code I'm looking at (which is only represented by the example I gave) that the type of the maximum is likely to change in the future.  That's why I wanted to be able to adjust to it.  Thanks for the answers.

Comment: `constexpr uint16_t MaxValue = 0xffff; ... if constexpr((std::numeric_limits<decltype(n)>::max)() > MaxValue) { if (n > MaxValue) {
     n = MaxValue;
   } } ...` is possible starting C++17; This should hopefully stop the compiler from complaining. The compiler optimizations would almost certainly have the same effect for the binaries though.

Comment: @fabian and Remy Lebeau: that's exactly what I was after. Thanks.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ I know `n` can't be greater than the type max.  I should have written it before the code example. I had it written it in my question, right after the code example.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

typeid results in a type_info const & rather than the type of variable, use

```
std::numeric_limits<decltype(variable)>::max()
```

instead.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
std:numeric_limits<decltype(n)>::max()
```

Comment: You mean `decltype(n)`?

Comment: OK, sure.  I guess that's more standard than `typeof`, but `typeof` does work in GCC.